# MAUI: custom behavior hangs

Tags: maui

I have this custom behavior attached to an `Entry` field:

```
public partial class SsnValidationBehavior : TextValidationBehavior
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty Iso2CountryProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Iso2Country), typeof(string), typeof(SsnValidationBehavior), "cl");

    public string Iso2Country
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(Iso2CountryProperty);
        set => SetValue(Iso2CountryProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool ChileValidate(string docNumber)
    {
        string rut = CleanRegex().Replace(docNumber, string.Empty).ToUpper();

        if (rut.Length >= 2)
        {
            string dv = rut[rut.Length - 1].ToString();
            if (MatchRegex().IsMatch(dv))
            {
                int largo = rut.Length;

                if (largo > 10 || largo < 2) return false;

                // La parte del RUT debe ser un número entero
                if (int.TryParse(rut.AsSpan(0, largo - 1), out _))
                {
                    // El dígito verificador debe ser un número o la K
                    if ((rut[largo - 1].CompareTo('0') < 0 || rut[largo - 1].CompareTo('9') > 0) && rut[largo - 1] != 'K')
                        return false;

                    // Realiza la operación módulo
                    int suma = 0;
                    int mul = 2;

                    // -2 porque rut contiene el dígito verificador, el cual no hay que considerar
                    for (int i = rut.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        suma += int.Parse(rut[i].ToString()) * mul;
                        if (mul == 7) mul = 2; else mul++;
                    }

                    int residuo = suma % 11;

                    char dvr;
                    if (residuo == 1)
                        dvr = 'K';
                    else if (residuo == 0)
                        dvr = '0';
                    else
                        dvr = (11 - residuo).ToString()[0];

                    return dvr.Equals(rut[^1]);
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected override async ValueTask<bool> ValidateAsync(string value, CancellationToken token)
    {
        bool result = true;
        string iso2 = Iso2Country ?? string.Empty;
        switch (iso2)
        {
            case "cl":
                result = ChileValidate(value);
                break;
        }

        return result && await base.ValidateAsync(value, token);
    }

    [GeneratedRegex("[ .-]")]
    private static partial Regex CleanRegex();
    [GeneratedRegex("[0-9K]")]
    private static partial Regex MatchRegex();
}
```

When I press any key in the field, the app hangs (even Visual Studio). I placed a breakpoint at `ValidateAsync` but it is not reached.

I took the model of this behavior from `https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Behaviors/Validators/EmailValidationBehavior.shared.cs`

Any help?

Comment: *"the app hangs"* - debug it. 1) Find what code *does* execute. Find the exact line that the app hangs on. Put breakpoints everywhere that should be reached, such as start of ChileValidate. 2) Where is the xaml that uses the custom behavior? Hard to know what might be wrong, if you don't show that. 3) If you can't find a hang by doing (1), then *remove* the use of custom behavior, to confirm it is cause of hang. Assuming it does not hang when you don't use custom behavior, then you need to find the exact line that causes problem: remove code or xaml till it stops hanging. What do you learn?

Comment: That it is not possible. Hang does not occur in my own code. I shown the full code of the behavior.

Comment: *"Hang does not occur in my own code."* OK, that makes it harder. Provide more information: 4) is *any* of your behavior code executed before the hang occurs? AND What about (2)? Add that XAML to question. AND Did you try (3) *"remove the use of custom behavior, to confirm it is cause of hang"*?

Answer (score 1):

Frist of all, I have created a new project to test your custom behavior. But I can't reproduce your problem. There is the code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp4.NewPage2"
             xmlns:mybehavior="clr-namespace:MauiAppTest"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             Title="NewPage2">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="InvalidEntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ValidEntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

  <Entry x:Name="entry">
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <mybehavior:SsnValidationBehavior
                InvalidStyle="{StaticResource InvalidEntryStyle}"
                ValidStyle="{StaticResource ValidEntryStyle}"
                Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged"
                MinimumLength="1"
                MaximumLength="10" />
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
</ContentPage>
```

And I have added the break point at the `ValidateAsync` and it can be hit. First, I saw the value of the `iso2` and `Iso2Country` always be `cl`(default value), so the `result && await base.ValidateAsync(value, token)` always be false. It seems you never called the Iso2Country's setter method.

In addition, I also check your last question. If you want to check the entry's text is null or empty. You can use the datatrigger to do that. Such as:

```
<Entry x:Name="entry">
        <Entry.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference entry}, Path=Text}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Pink"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference entry}, Path=Text.Length}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Pink"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Entry.Triggers>
    </Entry>
```